# fill kendogrid with api controller in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

i use from kendo grid but my grid dont fill with values and when show page grid dont load.
i use kendo 2014 and asp.net 2012.
my api controller code :

```
public class ValuesControllerApi : ApiController
{
    public List<File> Get()
    {
        GuaranteeEntities ef = new GuaranteeEntities();
        var file = ef.Files.Where(c => c.UpdaterUserInfo == "Guarantee").ToList();
        return file;
    }
}
```

and my html Code is :

```
 <div id="employeesGrid">
                        <script>
                            $(function () {
                                $("#employeesGrid").kendoGrid({
                                    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                        transport: {
                                            read: "/api/ValuesControllerApi"
                                        }
                                    })
                                });
                            });

                            $(function () {
                                $("#employeesGrid").kendoGrid({
                                    columns: [
                                        { field: "Name" , title:"test" },
                                        { field: "Family", title: "test test" }
                            ],
                            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                transport: {
                                    read: "/api/ValuesControllerApi"
                                }
                            }),
                            sortable: true
                            });
                            });

                         </script>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Did you try the bare api request in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try testing your API in the browser alone.

`localhost:12345/api/ValuesControllerApi` *(change your debugging url as required)*

Does that work? Chances are, it doesn't. The reason is because WebApi uses a default pattern for finding the controller end point. You can find [more info here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).

But to spare you the time, take note of this line:

> To find the controller, Web API adds "Controller" to the value of the {controller} variable.

What this means is by default, WebApi assumes all controller classes end in "*Controller*" when trying to route to an endpoint. In your case, you have named your API `ValuesControllerApi` which ends in "*Api*". Remove the "*Api*" from the class name and it should work.

So, your class name should look like this: `ValuesController : ApiController`

and you call it like this: `api/Values`

Answer (score 0):

I think that your controller action won't give Kendo Grid the results in the format it expects. You need to send it a DataSourceRequest. There is a simple example [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/tree/master/grid-webapi-crud/App_Code) you may check.

Also [this documentation article](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/webapi-editing) should shed some light on the issue too.

Hope it helps!