# Calling a C# class file from Typescript

Tags: c#, typescript

I am using typescript and kendo grid, and I want to call a method in a C# class object (ProcessData method in Utility.cs object). How would I call the C# file from typescript?

Answer (score 0):

`Type-Script` compiled into `java-script` and it's reside on client side (browser like Firefox, chrome) ... and `C# class` are used in serverside (the server your application hosted) .. so their is no chance to call c# class function directly from typescript class .. you have to expose c# class function as `Api service` and consume that service through `kendo-grid` function ...

You can check below links

[fill kendogrid with api controller in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23799214/fill-kendogrid-with-api-controller-in-asp-net)

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fc9f65/crud-operation-in-kendo-grid-using-web-api/

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/typescript

Comment: Are you sure JS cannot be used in serverside

Comment: @Jeon .. i hope you checked the question